# Evaluate $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{t^{s+2}s+2}$ for $s+2\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: limits

I would like to evaluate $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{t^{s+2}s+2}\tag{1}$$ for $s+2\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I think that the limit approaches $0$, but how may I prove this clearly?

It seems as though $s+2\gg 0$ as the closer $s+2$ is to $0$ the slower it converges to $0$.

Comment: What does mellin-transform even have to do with this?

Comment: @HasanSaad This is part of the result I get when finding the Mellin Transform of a function

Comment: Oh, okay, though I recommend you remove that tag as it's meaningless regarding the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $s>0$.

Let $X$ be the set of all numbers of the form $st^{s+2}$.

Assume $X$ is bounded above, then it must have a supremum $x$.

Thus, there exists a number $y$ such that

$\frac{x}{s+1}<s(\frac{y+1}{\sqrt[s+2]{s+1}})^{s+2}<x$ by the definition of the supremum and noting that  $s(\frac{y+1}{\sqrt[s+2]{s+1}})^{s+2}\in X$ by taking $t=\frac{y+1}{\sqrt[s+2]{s+1}}$

Multiplying all sides by $s+1$, we get

$x<s(y+1)^{s+2}<x(s+1)$

Thus, $x$ is not an upper bound, and thus the set is unbounded above, meaning that the limit of the denominator is $+\infty$ by noting that it the denominator is increasing as a function of $t$. Now, it is obvious that the limit is $0$.

The case where $s<0$ can be proved analogously by using the properties of boundedness below and infimum.

Answer (score 0):

If $s=0$, then your limit is $\frac 1 2$. If $s<0$ then it is $\frac 1 {-\infty} = 0$. If $s>0$ then it is $\frac 1 \infty = 0$. Don't worry, just use the arithmetic rules for dealing with $\infty$, they are absolutely rigorous. It would be useful to specify whether $0 \in \mathbb R ^+$, since this notation may mean different things in different countries.

Comment: He said "prove this", not "handwavy understand" this...Even if you use $\frac{1}{\infty}$, the problem is that you haven't even proved that the denominator goes to $\infty$ which is technically the gist of the whole proof...

Comment: @HasanSaad: I beg to disagree. To me, a computation _is_ a proof, as long as it is correctly done (and mine is). Even in textbooks for simple results you will encounter something like "proof: straight computation".

Comment: @HasanSaad: Wait a second: you mean that the OP asked for a proof of the fact that $\lim \limits _{t \to \infty} t^n = \infty$ when $n>0$? Come on!...

Comment: That is actually what I understood from his question. I'm pretty sure he doesn't mean dividing by $\infty$... Though in any case, OP's question still seems pretty trivial and I have no idea why anyone would ask such a question...

Comment: Or maybe he got all confused because of the presence of $s$ or whatever...

Comment: @HasanSaad: I agree with you; since the OP was asking this question in the context of working with the Mellin transform, I assume that he has at least a basic understanding of real analysis. Anyway, it is the OP's duty to step in and clarify the meaning of his question, not ours.

Comment: I doubt OP will even come anymore...

Comment: @HasanSaad I had to go to class. No, I have not taken Real Analysis, which is why I was looking for some help. You guys sure have cleared it up though between your comments and answers. I realized after I asked it was probably a bit trivial and tried to fill in a bit where my confusion was.

Comment: @jm324354: Real Analysis is the basis of it all. It wouldn't make sense to take other mathematics subjects without studying the fundamentals. It would be a serious mistake that would leave you with a significant mathematical vulnerability. Please consider this when choosing your study program.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for your suggestions. I'm at a community college until the end of the year, when I will achieve my Assc. in math, after which I will transfer to a nearby university (and I WILL be taking Real Analysis and as many other higher-level courses they have to offer). I was looking at their math programs about 20 minutes ago and I can't wait to finish up and get to the good stuff.